# Getting the caller name of a script

Tags: unix, process

I have a unix script. It has been called by some other script without proper arguments. Is there a way I can find out the caller name? grep didn't help as the name of the script is passed across several scripts and called dynamically. I want to get the script that ultimately calls my script? Anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no completely reliable for a UNIX process to know  *a posteriori* what process spawned it.  By the time your script (its `sh` interpreter) is `execve()`'d, its parent may have terminated or replaced itself with another program image.

That said, your script can remain calm and take reasonable guesses based on the process table and its own environment.

`ps -o args= $PPID` ought to portably show you the command line of your script's parent at the moment.  This will typically work.

If $PPID == 1, you've been orphaned and `init` is your adoptive parent.  `ps -o uid-,gid=,pgid=,tty= $$` will reveal your script's user and group ID, process group ID, and controlling terminal.  These are typically inherited directly from the parent without modification, and so might, with a little digging, help locate the session that spawned your group even if the parent itself terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) utility, which allows tracing system calls.

Here is one usage example from several on [this site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/):

```
$  strace ls
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8c31000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb78c7000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=65354, ...}) = 0
...
...
...
```

Comment: If the OP knew what program to `strace`, the OP would already know what program called his script.